# Arriving in UK before Tier 4 student visa becomes 'valid'

Tags: visas, uk, study

I'm from the USA, and have a UK tier 4 student visa already issued to me. They made an error on the date that it becomes 'valid', however I received the passport back only a week before flying, and don't have time to go through channels to change it.

I don't need a visa to enter the UK as a tourist (non-visa national, American citizens don't need separate visa to be tourist), so I was hoping I could visit as a tourist for the 7 days before my 30-day vignette in my passport becomes officially valid, then leave for a day and re-enter so that immigration can stamp my visa and officially 'activate it'.

Has anyone got any advice, or experience with this? It isn't my fault at all, I never meant to "sneak around" my visa. I have a full student visa, it's just that my 30-day sticker starts 7 days after it was meant to. I did my application correctly. There's just no time to fix it before I leave in 7 days.

**EDIT:** NO, this isn't a duplicate or the same as the question indicated, in any way. I ALREADY have the student visa, applied for it from my home country, all that deal. I have the visa. I simply want to know if anyone has any ideas or input regarding my ability to go into the UK as a tourist before the visa becomes valid, or if they'll say that since I currently have a student visa issued to me, despite it not being valid for another 7 days, I cannot enter as a tourist, depsite not needing a visa since USA citizens don't need tourist visas.

Comment: Suggest you email UK immigration, explain the situation and ask them what to do.

Comment: Not a duplicate. The OP already has a visa.

Comment: The question arises every September.  However... This type of question falls under the remit of our sister site, [Expats](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions).  This site is about tourism and very short-term visas.  Close voting in favour of migration to Expats.

Comment: The answer is, yes you can enter, but they may or may not stamp your visa. If they don't it means you are "just" a tourist and you are not allowed to work or study.  You must leave the country and enter again to get a stamp on the visa before you can start work/study.